# Rails options_for_select / ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to fetch `current_user.albums` to display on a `select` list.

```
<% album_options = current_user.albums { |a| [a.title, "#{a.title}-Album"] } %>

<%= select :screen, :attachable_id, options_for_select(album_options) %>
```

but i'm getting an output of:

```
<select id="screen_attachable_id" name="screen[attachable_id]">
  <option value="#<Album:0x007fe77bacf2a0>">#&lt;Album:0x007fe77bacf2a0&gt;</option>
</select>
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot about `map`:

```
<% album_options = current_user.albums.map { |a| [a.title, "#{a.title}-Album"] } %>
```

Comment: Lol... :D.. totally forgot it !